# Arduino IR Sensors Not Calling Functions

Tags: arduino

With this code written in the Arduino IDE I used to be able to call functions based on which Infrared sensor detected an object(right, left, or both). I altered the code a little bit lately but I've continued to make sure it wasn't missing any key components which made it work in the first place. I'm not sure if it's an error in my program or hardware but now, no matter what sensor detects an object, my robot just turns slightly to the left.

```
//Include Servo Library
#include <Servo.h>

//Define Pins for the Sensors and LEDs
#define LsensorPin 8
#define RsensorPin 5
#define LeftTransPin 7
#define RightTransPin 6
```

I'm using continuous rotation servos so using 0's and 180's is how I would control them at full speed. I checked the numbers over and over but they don't seem to be the problem.

```
//Constants for driving servo
const int RForward = 0; 
const int RBackward = 180; 
const int LForward = RBackward; 
const int LBackward = RForward; 
const int RNeutral = 90; 
const int LNeutral = 90; //0 Speed

//Name the Servos for Left and Right Motor
Servo LMotor;
Servo RMotor;
```

The following 2 functions, when called, transmit an infrared signal through the transmitters. I do not think this is related to the problem because the sensors still detect objects, but my robot just doesn't respond the way I want it to.

```
//Take Reading from Left IR Sensor
void LeftIRled(){
  for(int i=0;i<=384;i++){
   digitalWrite(LeftTransPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(13);
   digitalWrite(LeftTransPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(13);
 }
}

//Take Reading from Right IR Sensor
void RightIRled(){
  for(int i=0;i<=384;i++){
   digitalWrite(RightTransPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(13);
   digitalWrite(RightTransPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(13);
 } 
}
```

These functions control the direction in which the robot moves. I've checked it many times but this could possibly be one of the problems. They basically just control the spin of each individual servo with the previously declared variables.

```
//Controlling Servo Directions with Functions
void Forward(){
 RMotor.write(RForward);
 LMotor.write(LForward);
}
void Backup(){
 RMotor.write(RBackward);
 LMotor.write(LBackward);
}
void Stop(){
 RMotor.write(RNeutral);
 LMotor.write(LNeutral);
}
void Left(){
 RMotor.write(RForward);
 LMotor.write(LNeutral);
}
void Right(){
 RMotor.write(RNeutral);
 LMotor.write(LForward);
}

//Declare INPUT and OUTPUT for each Pin connected
//to Arduino Uno and set them to LOW
void setup(){
 pinMode(LeftTransPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(LeftTransPin, LOW);
 pinMode(RightTransPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(RightTransPin, LOW);

//drive forward
 LMotor.attach(9);
 RMotor.attach(10);
 Forward();
 }
```

Although I can't pinpoint the problem I believe it has something to do with the loop function. It is here that I transmit the infrared signal, receive it, and then call various functions which control the movement of the robot.

```
void loop(){

/*Drive forward until you reach an obstacle on either the 
right side, left side, or both together(something in front of
you).  If the left sensor goes low, he turns right, if the right
sensor goes low, he turns left.  if both turn on at the same time
he stops, backs up, and turns right till he is out of danger
*/
int lstate;
int rstate;

LeftIRled();
 lstate = digitalRead(LsensorPin);
 delay(50);
RightIRled();
 rstate = digitalRead(RsensorPin);
 delay(50);

if (lstate == LOW && rstate == LOW)
{
 Stop();
 delay(100);
 Backup();
 delay(1000);
 Stop();
 delay(100);
 Right();
 delay(500);
}
else if (lstate == LOW)
{
 Stop();
 delay(100);
 Backup();
 delay(1000);
 Right();
 delay(500);
}
else if (rstate == LOW)
{  
 Stop();
 delay(100);
 Backup();
 delay(1000);        
 Left();
 delay(500);
}
else
{
 Forward();
  }
}
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: On left() and right() is the one wheel locked when is at neutral or can it freely rotate because the other wheel is moving forward?

Comment: When turning yes one wheel is locked while the other is moving

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the other wheel turn the opposite direction?

Comment: I used to steer like that but I switched to the lock wheel method because the other way would turn too fast and I was looking for more precise adjustments so when roaming it wouldn't overshoot any obstacles. This one wheel steering was working fine for a while and just recently is my robot only turning left no matter what sensor I trigger

Comment: Have you done debugging (by means of printing the the serial monitor) to see what the states are?

Comment: Yes I have and both infrared sensors are working properly that's why I'm having so much trouble narrowing down the problem

Comment: Does the left sensor trigger only when left shoudl and right trigger only when right should?

Comment: Yes they both trigger but neither call the functions stop backup and turn left or right

Comment: That makes no sense; if for instance lstate is LOW then in the very least Stop() will be called. Have you Serial.print() from inside Stop() to see if it is called?